# how to work history.js random first state

Tags: javascript, jquery, pushstate, history.js

I'm using history.js (html4+html5) since years, but I'm in front of a problem I can't understand.
In fact, when I load a page where I need "history.js", sometime if I don't do a "pushState" on load, it won't remember this state (i.e. when I'll use back button it will never get back to that state, it just skip it). But that's totally random :/. Sometime it don't need the pushState, sometimes it need it.

Any known issue about that, please ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: some code might be helpfull

Comment: please give versions, a jsfiddle or post code and markup where we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, I'm using html4+html5 version, on the latest release.
Latest jQuery 1.x too.
You can see it on my live website : http://www.luminis-films.com/films_pour_vitrages/film_occultant/film_opacifiant
I use it to keep a track on the filter change. Just play with the filter to see it in action. The JS is minified, but the problem line is :

Comment: jQuery(function($) {
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){var state = History.getState();if (typeof(state.data.donnees)!='undefined'){liste.miseAJour(state.data.donnees)}});
History.pushState({donnees:$film_liste[0].outerHTML},document.title,window.location.href);
});

Answer (score 0):

I always replace the initial state on DOM load, and have not experienced your problem.

```
var initalHistory = function () {
    var State = History.getState(), data = State.data;
    if (!data.rendered) {
        History.replaceState(null, null "ExampleString");
        }
    }
History.Adapter.onDomLoad(initalHistory);
```